# Trying to make Textblocks visible on Radiobutton click WP8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

This is my 1st C# Code so I'm a noob please be kind. I'm trying to make a group of text blocks visible on radio button click but I keep getting this error:

> An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'MathApp2.AppSettings.RadioButton3Setting.get

MainPage is the 1st page of the app that contains the TextBlocks I'm trying to turn on and off. I created them with Xaml not in the C# code itself. AppSettings is a class very similar to this code: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff769510(v=vs.105).aspx The code in Question is located on Page 2 (Settings Page) of the app that contains the Radiobuttons.

I guess I need to pass an instance of the MainPage and AppSettings into Page 2(Settings Page)??

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Getting the error on all the starred lines of this code:

```
private void radioButton3_Checked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (AppSettings.RadioButton3Setting == true) *
    {
        MainPage.TextBlock5.Visible = true;      *
        MainPage.TextBlock6.Visible = true;      *
        MainPage.TextBlock7.Visible = true;      *
        MainPage.TextBlock8.Visible = true;      *
    }
    else
    {
        MainPage.TextBlock5.Visible = false;     *
        MainPage.TextBlock6.Visible = false;     *
        MainPage.TextBlock7.Visible = false;     *
        MainPage.TextBlock8.Visible = false;     *
    }
}
```

Comment: why is the method static? If it's on the code behind of the same view, remove the static and use the controls directly. TextBlock6.Visible

Comment: its not I forgot to take that out before I posted

Comment: I guess `MainPage` is class name for the Page. If those codes are in `MainPage`, try to remove `MainPage` so it is become like : `TextBlock5.Visible = true;` and see if the error gone.

Answer (score 0):

From the error message, it appears that `AppSettings` is a class you had to instantiate at some point, but now you're trying to access a property as if it were static.

If you create an instance of `AppSettings`, use that instead:

```
if (myInstanceOfAppSettings.RadioButton3Setting == true)
```

---

The same goes for `MainPage`. Those `TextBlock` controls are also only accessible on an instance of `MainPage`, but you're accessing them as if they're static.

Assuming the `TextBlock` controls are in the same window as that click event, just remove `MainPage.` from the beginning of each line.

If the `TextBlock` controls are in another window, and you've passed an instance of it into whatever window you've posted in your question, use that instance instead:

```
someInstanceOfMainPage.TextBlock5.Visible = true;
someInstanceOfMainPage.TextBlock6.Visible = true;
```

Comment: I think I need to create an instance of both AppSettings and MainPage but im not sure exactly how to do that